# How to fetch all videos in custom page which uploaded in wp-admin (Media) in wordpress

Tags: videos, audio

I want to fetch all videos which are uploaded in back end wp-admin media.

How to show all videos or audios which I uploaded on a custom page?

Comment: Did you already tried something?

Comment: Yes, I tried two ways.
1st:  By static query
2nd: By function of get_post
which one is good and do you have any other option to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploaded images, video's etc. are stored as posts with the type "attachment"; use [`get_posts( )`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) with the right parameters.

Try this; the code loops trough all attachments and displays them:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'attachment',
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_status' => null,
  'post_parent' => null, // any parent
  'post_mime_type' => 'YOUR-POST-MIME-TYPE'
); 

$attachments = get_posts( $args );

if ( $attachments ) {
  foreach ( $attachments as $post ) {
    setup_postdata( $post );
    the_title( );
    the_attachment_link( $post->ID, false );
    the_excerpt( );
  }
}
```

Where `YOUR-POST-MIMET-YPE` is the mime-type you're looking for.

> A full or partial mime-type, e.g. image, video, video/mp4, which is matched against a post's post_mime_type field

So in your case you should try `video`.
You also could use `array( 'video', 'another-mime-type' )` for multiple mime-types.

Comment: Dear Mike Maders, Can you describe 'numberposts' => -1, means. how many post does it return ?

Comment: `numberposts` is used to query _x_ amount of posts; `'numberposts' => -1` stands for **all posts**.

Comment: Dear Mike Madern, If i want to show just 4 records so is it should be numberposts => 4 .. Is it right ? Anyhow Thank you :)

Comment: Yes, thats right ;-)

Comment: Dear Mike Madern, Thanks for your support. Everything is working fine except video thumbnail. I added thumbnail image of video. May you please tell me how to get video thumbnail too ?

Comment: That is another question, you can ask a new question for that ;-)